# double to char matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to have the following :

> 'This variable is pointer'

I have

```
a = get_param(....)
```

=>this gives me : pointer 
know to have the string above I did :

```
strcat('This variable is',a)
```

but this gives me :

> 'This variable in pointer'

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, by providing some details and possibly additional code?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to work out what you are trying to do.

The current title 'double to char matlab' indicates you are trying to convert a double to a string (char?).

There are many functions that can do this in Matlab:

```
a=3.1;

num2str(a)

sprintf('The value is %g', a );
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with:

```
strcat('This variable is',a)
```

but the only way I can think of that you could actually get:

```
'This variable in pointer'
```

is if you had set a with something like:

```
a = sprintf('\bn pointer');
```

If a was set to 'pointer' then

```
strcat('This variable is',a)
```

would result in:

```
'This variable ispointer'
```

Even if you added a space after is you would get the same result because strcat trims whitespace before concatenating.

You'd be better off using :

```
['This variable is ' a]
```

to concatenate the 2 strings.

Comment: hello grantnz, thanks for your answer, so I can use : b= num2str(a); then x = ['This variable is ' b]  ? this take into accoun spaces ?